# Chrome extension to delete a line inside script tag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

There is a webpage that has a `<script>` tag with a lot of functions.

I want to make a Chrome Extension in order to delete a specific line that appears many times in the script every time I access this website.

Is there a way to do that?

Ex.

```
<script>
    function a(){
         var a = 10;
         settimeout(10);
    }
    function b(){
         var b = 40;
         settimeout(40);
    }
</script>
```

I want to delete every `settimeout` call.

Comment: there might be a way with a chrome extension i dont know, but could you just redefine the function? `window.setTimeout = function(f){  /* do nothing */ };`

Comment: Yes, redefine window.setTimeout as shown above, just make sure to do it [in the web page context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879).